# Static java issue

Tags: java

I have two classes one is:

```
public class Emp {
    String name;
    static int bankVault;
    }
```

and the other one is:

```
public class TestEmp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Emp emp1 = new Emp();
    Emp emp2 = new Emp();
    emp1.bankVault = 10;
    emp2.bankVault = 20;
    System.out.println(emp1.bankVault);
    System.out.println(emp2.bankVault);
    System.out.println(Emp.bankVault);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
20
20
20
```

Is this because of the `static` word? Shouldn't the first `System.out.println` return 10?

Comment: this is the sample to show how "static" works. you have only one bankValault. so you always get same value

Comment: See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: 10 will be overridden with 20, that is with latest value. Always one value can set to static fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is because of the word `static`. The use of `static` means you don't need an instance of an object to access it.

It can be accessed with `Emp.bankVault`. The property is initialized when the `class Emp` is loaded so there is no need for an instance of `Emp` object.

Once it's set, it will have the same value regardless of the `Emp` instance you use to read it from.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `static` means "one per class" not "one per instance". Once you modify it you modify it for ALL instances.